# top-level statement cannot begin with a closure expression

Tags: swift, function, anonymous-function

I'm learning anonymous functions and "define-and-call" functions in Swift using this [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_swift_compiler#) (since I don't have a Mac), and I wrote this code to try out what I have learnt by making an anonymous function that adds two numbers and prints the result:

```
{
    (a:Int, b:Int) -> Void in
    print(a + b)
} (2,3)
```

When I tried to run this function, the compiler gives me an error:

```
main.swift:10:1: error: top-level statement cannot begin with a closure expression
{
^


...Program finished with exit code 0
```

I managed to work around with to this by making a second function like this:

```
func doIt() {
    {
        (a:Int, b:Int) -> Void in
        print(a + b)
    } (2,3)
}

doIt()
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, because I don't understand why the compiler didn't let me run the anonymous function as call. The compiler also mentions the file I write in as `main.swift`, which I heard allows executable code to run in the top level.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap the code in a `do {}` if you want to run it directly

```
do {
    { (a:Int, b:Int) -> Void in
        print(a + b)
    } (2,3)
}
```

or you can create a variable out of your closure and then call it using the variable

```
let doIt = { (a:Int, b:Int) -> Void in
    print(a + b)
}

doIt(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be explained in the source:

```
  // Expressions can't begin with a closure literal at statement position.
  // This prevents potential ambiguities with trailing closure syntax.
  if (Tok.is(tok::l_brace)) {
    diagnose(Tok, diag::statement_begins_with_closure);
  }
```